# Uncaught TypeError in Chosen library on Windows 7

Tags: jquery

I use Chosen for creating a searchable `select`. My code works on my PC, but on some PCs Chosen does not work.

I've checked on Ubantu 16.04LTS and Chrome version 74.0.3729.131 and this is supported. I've also checked on Windows 7 and Chrome 80 and this is not supported.

This is the error I see in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function.

I've also tried Select2, and also get the same error. Is it a problem with the OS or Chrome version? How could I resolve this?

```js
$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('select').chosen();
  
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('select').val("Select Medicine");
    $('select').trigger("chosen:updated");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.5.1/chosen.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.5.1/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:520px;margin:0px auto;margin-top:30px;">
  <h2>One of the Best Plugin for Select Box with Search Option</h2>
  <select class="livesearch" style="width:400px;">
    <option value="Select Medicine">Select Medicine</option>
    <option>Expert PHP</option>
    <option>Demo PHP</option>
    <option>PHP Tutorials</option>
    <option>PHP Framework</option>
    <option>PHP Libraries</option>
    <option>HTML</option>
    <option>CSS</option>
    <option>JS</option>
    <option>MySQL</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button id="click">Click</button>
```

I've check on window 10 google version 80 on this is working. What is exactly issue not understand. Can you please suggest function for searchable select option instead of select2 or chosen which is work on all browser.

Comment: The OS will not be the issue. The browser you're using may be, although I've never heard of Chosen or Select2 having any compatibility issues with modern browsers. In fact they are *very widely* used. Note that the code in your question works fine on all browsers I've tested in. Without seeing the code which causes the problem, we can't help you.

Comment: I've check on window 10 google version 80 on this is working. What is exactly issue not understand. Can you please suggest function for searchable select option instead of select2 or chosen which is work on all browser.